# Playback of a video stored on Camera Roll?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, air-native-extension

I'm having trouble trying to playback a video stored on an iOS device's camera roll.

This is an **Adobe AIR** app, using two air native extensions (**ANE**):

- one extension for picking media (images and videos from the gallery)
- another extension for playback with `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Here is the error code caught in the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`:

```
Error: Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x8a0a20 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Here is the code for the media picker ANE:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  if (self.popover) {
    [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popover = nil;
  } else {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    picker = nil;
  }

  NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

  // Handle a movie
  if (CFStringCompare((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
  {
    self.videoPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
  }
}

// This function is called by the native extension to retrieve the path of the video.
DEFINE_ANE_FUNCTION(getVideoPath)
{
  NSLog(@"Entering getVideoPath");
  FREObject retValue = NULL;

  NSString *videoPath = [[AirImagePicker sharedInstance] videoPath];
  FRENewObjectFromUTF8(strlen([videoPath UTF8String])+1,
                     (const uint8_t *)[videoPath UTF8String],
                     &retValue);

  NSLog(@"Exiting getVideoPath");
  return retValue;
}
```

And here is the code for the playback ANE:

```
DEFINE_ANE_FUNCTION(loadVideo)
{
  uint32_t stringLength;

  NSString *path = nil;
  const uint8_t *urlString;
  if (FREGetObjectAsUTF8(argv[0], &stringLength, &urlString) == FRE_OK)
  {
    path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)urlString];
  }

  if (path)
  {
    [[[AirVideo sharedInstance] player] setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    [[[AirVideo sharedInstance] player] play];
  }

  return NULL;
}

DEFINE_ANE_FUNCTION(showPlayer)
{
  UIView *rootView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] view];
  [rootView addSubview:[[[AirVideo sharedInstance] player] view]];

  return nil;
}


- (MPMoviePlayerController *)player
{
    if (!_player)
    {
        // Initializer movie player
        _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

        // Register for notifications
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerLoadStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:_player];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_player];
    }

    return _player;
}
```

A trace for the video path shows this:

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/5912AED1-S1DE-25EF-A8B-EF7AD21E3R65/tmp//trim.‌​uUcGJU.MOV
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the name of the movie has to dots in it ? Did you try to play that movie directly from the camera roll not from your app ?

Comment: @danypata the video plays as expected from the camera roll app.  I can even play it on the UIImagePickerController before selecting it.